# Unable to connect to Airflow webserver in docker

Tags: docker, localhost, airflow

I am trying to run Apache Airflow in docker, and despite webserver seems to be correctly switch on, I can reach the webserver from my localhost.

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    container_name: data-webserver
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: data-postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ADD . .
ADD ./docker_src/my_folder /etc
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTONPATH}:/maintenance:/database_utils:/utils"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip mysql-server
RUN pip install -r docker_src/requirements.pip
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

**Airflow init:**

```
airflow initdb
```

**Airflow webserver:**

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

**Airflow webserver response:**

```
2019-04-26 08:10:13 +0000] [31] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-04-26 08:10:13 +0000] [31] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (31)
[2019-04-26 08:10:13 +0000] [31] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-04-26 08:10:13 +0000] [36] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36
[2019-04-26 08:10:13,684] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-04-26 08:10:13 +0000] [37] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 37
[2019-04-26 08:10:13,746] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-04-26 08:10:13 +0000] [41] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 41
[2019-04-26 08:10:13 +0000] [42] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 42
[2019-04-26 08:10:13,850] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-04-26 08:10:13,866] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-04-26 08:10:13,974] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-04-26 08:10:14,058] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-04-26 08:10:14,156] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-04-26 08:10:14,164] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-04-26 08:10:34 +0000] [31] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
[2019-04-26 08:10:35 +0000] [31] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
[2019-04-26 08:10:44 +0000] [31] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-04-26 08:10:44 +0000] [56] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 56
[2019-04-26 08:10:44,937] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-04-26 08:10:45,143] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-04-26 08:10:45 +0000] [31] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-04-26 08:10:45 +0000] [36] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 36)
[2019-04-26 08:11:16 +0000] [31] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-04-26 08:11:16 +0000] [61] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 61
[2019-04-26 08:11:16,198] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-04-26 08:11:16,441] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-04-26 08:11:17 +0000] [31] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-04-26 08:11:17 +0000] [37] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 37)
[2019-04-26 08:11:47 +0000] [31] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
[2019-04-26 08:11:47 +0000] [66] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 66
[2019-04-26 08:11:47,453] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-04-26 08:11:47,670] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-04-26 08:11:48 +0000] [31] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
[2019-04-26 08:11:48 +0000] [41] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 41)
```

When I run from my computer: `http://localhost:8080/`
I can't reach the website despite I expose the port in the docker-compose.

Where is the issue?

**Docke ps output**

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
9aa56948cdf6        analytics-etl_webserver   "/bin/sh -c 'tail -f…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   data-webserver
20db5fd63ad8        postgres:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 hours ago         Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   data-postgres
```

Comment: How about checking the output of `docker ps` it should show at what ip and port its running, if its running.

Comment: @Biranjan just added

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás No, sorry. Still stopped this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `compose file`, we can see that you haven't mapped your `webserver's`container port `(8080)` to the host.

Your `docker-compose.yml` should look something like below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    container_name: data-webserver
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: data-postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have seen that and I just fixed it. I am building it again.

Comment: You don't have to rebuild the image. You just have to update your `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: Well I run: docker-compose up -d --build

The thing is that it doesn't work neither. It returns 0.0.0.0 doesn't send any data.

Comment: can you share the output of `docker-compose ps`?